# Salesforce1 Notifications for Community Users

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, chatter

We have Salesforce1 app notifications setup for our Community Plus license Users for when they receive chatter mentions. When chatter mentions are received the Users receive a Push notification outside of the app and an email notification, but no in app notification (nothing on the bell at the top right).

Non Community members do get these in app notifications, and all the necessary settings for in app notifications are set, from what I can tell.

Comment: Sorry, but have you resolved this issue?

Comment: @OlesMalkov unfortunately we never did. I don't know if things have changed since we last tried though.

Comment: We have a similar issue for Community Plus. Will be logging a case with Salesforce for this issue.